# Cannot run C program from command prompt on windows 10

Tags: c, gcc, command-prompt

I am using Windows 10 OS. I installed MinGW for compiling C programs. I tried running my program using the gcc command on the Command Prompt. The file compiles and an executable file(.exe) is formed in the same folder as my source file. But when I try running this file, I keep getting the message 'Access is denied'. Also the .exe file vanishes after this. I do not know what is wrong. Please help me out.

P.S Another time I did the same thing mentioned above and the .exe file ran and I was able to see the output on the Command line. And this time the .exe file did not vanish either.

Comment: Is this a company laptop? Sounds like some super invasive virusscanner / shield.
Maybe the signature of your EXE looked like a type of malware and the virusscanner intervened (a so called false positive)

Comment: You can put Win10 into "Devloper's Mode" that will allow you to side-load (run) programs you compile and that will bypass Windows Defender restrictions. It is in the settings, search "Win 10 enable developer mode" for the exact details. [How to enable Developer Mode in Windows 10 to sideload apps ...](https://www.ghacks.net/2015/06/13/how-to-enable-developer-mode-in-windows-10-to-sideload-apps/)

Comment: @E.vanPutten This is not a company laptop. It is my personal laptop.

Comment: Okay. So did you check to see if there is any anti-virus software? Because what you have seen is a typical "quarantine" action: first the AV software blocks access to the file and then moves the file to another location (or outright deletes it).

Answer (score 0):

What was the command you put to compile the program? Also to compile and make an executable file, you have to put this command - "gcc -o nameofexecutablefile nameofsourcefile.c", to run this program just type the name of your executable file in cmd. And to stop the program's window from closing, put "system("pause");" right before the "return 0;" in your program, at the end of the program it will display "Press any key to continue..." and when you press any key, the window will close. Also check if you did any mistakes in your program. I'll also give an example -

------------CODE-----------

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    printf("Hello World\n");

    system("pause"); // this will pause the window
    return 0;
}
```

-------OUTPUT--------

```
Hello World
Press any key to continue...
```

Comment: I have given the same command you mention here. And there is no error in the program. It's just the simple hello world program which you have also given as your example.

Comment: What confuses me is that this problem is not a constant. Sometimes when I try running C programs, they run perfectly fine. At other times, no matter what I try, I get the same message 'Access is denied'. The change is usually after a reboot.